# How to do template strings for Safari?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation

I heve following template literal:

```
<ListItemText primary={`Price in sector ${index}`} />
<TextField
InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
defaultValue={price}
onBlur={e => this.savePrice(e, index)}
/>
```

but in some reason in Safari debugger it looks like this. Do you have any idea what is wrong with it?

[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem? Safari clearly has terrible syntax highlighting, but then Safari's debugger isn't a code editor. Check to see if https://bugs.webkit.org/ already has an issue for it, and file one if there isn't, but there's nothing actually wrong here in terms of the code itself, or even the code execution.

Comment: It's pretty common for new features to be available but syntax highlighting for these features lags behind.

Comment: The problem is hardly the template string, but rather your use of jsx syntax (which I doubt Safari would support, given it's not in the EcmaScript standard)

Comment: What should be the correct jsx synctacs? :D